# Lwip how print source and destination IP during send phase in UDP

Tags: c, udp, ip, ipv4, lwip

I am using Lwip with the SAM V71 generated by atmel start. I have two destination IP "192.168.1.220" on port 48752 and "192.168.1.225" on port 48753.

I am transmitting data to both IP's. how to I print the destination IP at the point of transmission.

I have tried enabling LWIP's debug mode for UDP and ID but there is nothing being printed in the terminal.

Comment: Without a little more explanation it almost seems like it's your program that initiates the transmission, which means the destinations must be known to your program. And that means you could easily print them out yourself. And even if you're just replying to an incoming packet, the source address of that packet (the destination of the reply) should be possible to retrieve (otherwise you would not be able to reply) and to print.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry for the very late reply you were right when the LwIP receiver callback is invoked on receiving data the senders IP address and port address can be obtained from the struct ip_addr *addr and uint16_t port arguments which passed from within the LwIP Library.




`printf("IP Address    : %s\r\n", ipaddr_ntoa(((const ip_addr_t *)&addr->addr)));`

`printf("Port Address  : %d\r\n", port);`